# Regex to match full name with comma or space

Tags: php, regex, commonmark

I'm working with CommonMark and I've created a '@mention' parser that will return a link when an @mention is found. However, I'm tweaking it to link full names instead of usernames. Here's what I currently have:

```
$cursor->match('/^\w+,(.*)\s/');
```

However, this seems to capture the name incorrectly, and links the start of the other name (see below):

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas what I could change to match an entire name separated with a comma **and/or space**? I'm awful at writing regex.

Thanks for any help in advance!

**Edit:**

Here's what should match:

(A name can only be 2 words minimum and 3 words maximum)

- Bauman, Steve
- Steve Bauman
- Doe, Mary Sue
- Mary Sue Doe

A last name with a comma will **only** be one word.

What should not match:

- Steve
- Bauman
- Mary
- Doe

The regex needs to match an entire name, not single names.

This is the CommonMark code behind the `match` method:

```
if (!preg_match($regex, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    return;
}
```

This results to:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\w+,(.*)\s/', "Bauman, Steve", $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: What are the exact rules for the regex? It'll be much simpler if you added a sample input and a set of results that should match and shouldn't match.

Comment: can you try it once : ^\w+|,|\s|\w

Comment: Hi @degant, sorry about that, I'm editing the question now.

Comment: No problem, so as per your updated rules, a name will be 2 seperate words. Is that always true? What if a name has 3 parts?

Comment: @degant Shoot! I forgot about a three part name (which we do have in our organization), I've updated my rules, thanks!

Comment: @Jeet, unfortunately this doesn't work, thank you though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your new rules, match a name that has 2 or 3 words and should be separated by spaces ( ) or commas (,)

```
/\w+([, ]+\w+){1,2}/
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/s9GKNt/2)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOS
something @name, bla bla bla @name.surname something else
Lorem ipsum @o'brien 
EOS;

$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/@[^\s,]+/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

and working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d9b570a50b8fea89d9f8f174a595d3ffb556486)

Comment: Unforuntately this doesn't work, for example inserting '@Bauman, Steve' results to an array containing "@Bauman" and not "@Bauman, Steve"